# How to show jquery confirmation dialogue with multiple forms and submit buttons mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a mvc project and on one page there is a table of data with a submit button that is inside its own form tag.  I want to have a pop up modal dialogue when the user clicks the delete button to ask for confirmation of the delete.  How would you do this with jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the ajax.actionlink

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteUser", new { id = user.user_id }, new AjaxOptions { Confirm = "Are You sure to delete?", UpdateTargetId = "article_1" })
```